# Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) friezes while installing lxml on termux

Tags: pip, lxml, python-3.7, termux

I was trying to install lxml on python 3.7.4 on Termux on my phone:

```
$ pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/43/3f1e7d742e2a7925be180b6af5e0f67d38de2f37560365ac1a0b9a04c015/lxml-4.4.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... -
```

But the process has taken hours and it seemed like it froze.

I already have `libxml2, libxslt, libiconv, clang` packages installed
and also `pip wheel`

Can it be that this depends on my RAM and if so, what can I do about it?

Please help me out guys:p

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the procedure you're following is correct and gets the job done. It does take a while to install based on the resources available to it, on my previous OnePlus 3, I left the process on for an entire night, I didn't calculate the exact time it took but when I woke up lxml was installed. Hope this helps.

Comment: P.S. It does look like installation freezed but if you can use your phone, like the keyboard opens and closes or you can multitask then it has not frozen, android will automatically show you an ANR Dialog if it does.